# IIF Case inside RDLC Lookupset

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

Everytime I tried I am getting an error on the report.
Do you see any mistake on my expression?

```
   =IIf(CInt(Join(LookupSet(Fields!ID.Value, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!Value.Value, "xxx")))=1,Chr(82) + VbCrlf, Chr(163) + VbCrlf)
```

And I also tried

```
   =Join(LookupSet(Fields!ID.Value, Fields!ID.Value,IIf( Fields!Value.Value, Chr(82), Chr(163)),"xxx"))
```

Comment: Thanks I fixed the tag

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: As a side note,  using `&` instead of `+` for working with string concatenations is preferred as it prevents possible conversion errors.

Comment: It says just an #error